# Ipconfig release / renew is not changing dynamically

Tags: windows-7

I've got my Win 7 pc using Dynamic IP.  I tried an ipconfig renew then release but I still get a the same 192....rest for my PC, it doesn't chagne the IPv4

Comment: forgot to add that this is a basic desktop PC at home over comcast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no policy that requires a DHCP server to give a different address to a machine when a new address is requested. It must be configured by the system administrator to explicitly do so, provided the software allows it.

Comment: this is a home PC (comcast cable modem) and a wireless linksys router

Comment: The answer stands regardless.

Comment: so I'm stuck with whatever Comcast's dns server serves to me

Comment: DHCP, not DNS​.

Comment: so then at a work situation, in the past if you have it set to dhcp on your PC, you could always reboot to get another IP...is that no longer the case?  I'm not a network guru so bear with me.

Comment: There is normally no correlation between when a machine requests an address and which address it gets.

Comment: so rebooting a windows machine really was a myth in order to "get a new address for dhcp"?

Comment: It may give you a new address, or it may not. But there is no direct external way to influence that.

Comment: What IP address you get all depends on the DHCP pool and DHCP lease time. If the lease your computer gets is not up, you will get the same IP handed out, if your lease is expired, you will get the next address in the pool, which will likely be the same IP if no other device has connected since.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [MadMacs](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/madmacs-mac-spoofer) to change your MAC address. Most likely the router on the other end is set up to hand out IPs on leases depending on MAC addresses in the arp table. In this case, getting a new MAC address means getting a new IP. Keep in mind that this may or may not work, depending on your ISPs configuration.